# Create two columns (interval) from a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` with a column

```
Value

3
8
10 
15
```

I would like to obtain a dataframe that has an 'interpolated' `From` `To` values as the following:

```
Value From To
Nan    0   3
3      3   5
Nan    5   8
8      8   10
10     10  12
Nan    12  15
15     15  17
```

The increment is always 2 when a value exist.

Comment: I don't get how is it going from `3 3 5` to `Nan 5 8`? 5 comes from 'To' to 'Value' - that's clear. But why 8? Shouldn't it be 7 then? And if it should, then how are you supposed to get to 8 if increment is always 2?

Comment: The increment of 2 is valid only if there is a value (3 to 5, 8 to 10, 10 to 12 and 15 to 17). But I need to have value `From` starting at 0 and `To` ending at the last `Value + 2`, without empties between `To` and the next `From`( I cannot have 3 to 5 and  8 to 10, I need a `To` and `From` between 5 and 8)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

This is the starting dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value' : [0, 2,5,7,9,14,21,25]})
df['From'] = df['Value']
df['To'] = df['Value'] + 2

>>> print(df)
   Value  From  To
0      0     0   2
1      2     2   4
2      5     5   7
3      7     7   9
4      9     9  11
5     14    14  16
6     21    21  23
7     25    25  27
```

And this code allow to habe `From`and `To` columns without empties intervals

```
new_rows = []
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    if df.loc[i, 'To'] != df.loc[i+1, 'Value']:
        new_row = {'Value': np.nan,'From': df.loc[i, 'To'], 'To': df.loc[i+1, 'Value']}
    else:
        new_row = {'Value': np.nan, 'From': np.nan, 'To': np.nan}
    new_rows.append(new_row)

df1 = df.append(new_rows, ignore_index=True)
df1.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
df1.sort_values(by=['To'], inplace=True)
df1

>>> df1
    Value  From    To
0     0.0   0.0   2.0
1     2.0   2.0   4.0
9     NaN   4.0   5.0
2     5.0   5.0   7.0
3     7.0   7.0   9.0
4     9.0   9.0  11.0
12    NaN  11.0  14.0
5    14.0  14.0  16.0
13    NaN  16.0  21.0
6    21.0  21.0  23.0
14    NaN  23.0  25.0
7    25.0  25.0  27.0
```

It is probably improvable....